# How can i select value id from a tr inside of a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get value id from a tr inside of a iframe but i cant do that because i cant get values from a iframe.

I have the next iframe:

```
<table id="table_values">
 <tr id="value_1">
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="value_2">
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get "value_1" when I clicked above tr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are both the `iframe` and main page from same domain?

Comment: No, I'am trying to access the iframe in other domain